# Get the package details of a class in karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

My requirement is to get the package of a class loaded in karaf. I was able to do this in karaf by using the command **bundle:find-class**.

Is there an equivalent for this function in java. Are there any other solutions for this problem.

**Note**: I have tried using Reflections as well as Google Reflections. This works as a java program. When i deploy this in karaf the functions return null.

Comment: What did you try ? a simple `class.getPackage().getName()` ? Your issue is about loading a particular class by name ?

Comment: I know a package name. i need to know all the classes inside that package. What i am trying to achieve is the same functionality as the karaf command bundle:find-class.

Comment: Your question is about "details of a class", not "all the class in a package in a bundle"... Anyway, Karaf is an open source, just check the source : https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/command/FindClass.java

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i was trying to achieve both the functionality. If i give a package name, It should give me all the classes. If i give a class name it should give me the complete package name.